# Autoheight the outer div

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I am trying to set the height of div#container to auto based on which is positioned relative and inner div's positioned absolute and middle of the container.

```
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="container">
    <div class="items" id="item1">Item 1</div>
    <div class="items" id="item1">Item 2</div>
    <div class="items" id="item1">Item 3</div>
    <div class="items" id="item1">Item 4</div>
    <div class="items" id="item1">Item 5</div>
    <div class="items" id="item1">Item 6</div>
</div>
```

Please find the demo below and help me to achieve the design like in below image

[image]

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Coolenough/eq5ygb23/

Comment: A parent can't be relative to childs that are only absolute. At least one of the child `items` has to be relative to calculate the container height.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Steyn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an extra relative inner-container that can be positioned relatively to the parent #container and hold the positioned absolute .items.

```css
#header {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}

#container {
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.inner-container{
    position:relative;
    width: 80px;
    height: 40px;
    margin:50px auto;
}

.items {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #38c;
    width: 80px;
    height: 40px;
    color: #ffffff;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="container">
    <div class="inner-container">
        <div class="items" id="item1">Item 1</div>
        <div class="items" id="item1">Item 2</div>
        <div class="items" id="item1">Item 3</div>
        <div class="items" id="item1">Item 4</div>
        <div class="items" id="item1">Item 5</div>
        <div class="items" id="item1">Item 6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```